# How to update `attr_accessor` on selected ActiveRecords from ActiveRelation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, attr-accessor

## Introduction

Let's say that I have a model declaration of a Book with `attr_accessor` named `:purchased`.

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  # contains fields like :id, :title, :description, :archived_at
  ...

  attr_accessor :purchased

  def purchased
    @purchased || false
  end

  scope :unarchived, -> { where(archived_at: nil) }

  ...
end
```

## Problem

I have an arbitrary method

```
def mark_purchased(purchased_ids)
  # 1. Returns ActiveRecord::Relation
  unarchived_books = Book.unarchived

  # 2. Mark only purchased books
  purchased_books = unarchived_books.where(id: purchased_ids)
  purchased_books.update_attr_accessor(purchased: true)

  # 3. Return unarchived books with update :purchased attr_accessor
  unarchived_books
end
```

This method takes an `ActiveRecord::Relation` and updates `attr_accessor` on a subset of this relation, and then should return the whole relation with updated attr_accessor

## Question

How to accomplish this with the lowest amount of code and as efficient as possible?

Let's assume that we have 200 000 books and the user purchased only 50 of them and let's avoid the pagination solution for now. I know that I'm going to call `:purchased` 200 000 times when displaying them, but I want to update only a subset of `unarchived_books` (50 records to be specific) instead of looping through all books and checking if they are in `purchased_ids`.

The best solution that I thought of, was to

1. Get all unarchived books
2. Get a subset and update them one by one using `.each` loop (because there is nothing like `:update_attr_accessor` on whole `ActiveRecord::Relation`
3. Merge these relations together, overriding the first relation with updated one.

But there's one problem with number 3 of my solution - the `:merge` method  actually ignores the `attr_accessors`, so I have no idea where to go from there.

Do you have any tips on how to improve my solution?

Comment: Is the slow option actually slow? It involves looping through 200000 records, but I'm not sure how your "Merge" step would avoid a similar loop.

Answer (score 1):

Loading and updating all the records one by one is guaranteed to run out of memory with a non trivial amount of data. The fastest way is to use `update_all` which updates all the records in a single query without instantiating them:

```
def mark_purchased(purchased_ids)
  purchased_books = Book.unarchived.where(id: purchased_ids)
  purchased_books.update_all(purchased: true) 
  purchased_books
end
```

If you really have to update them one by one for example to trigger callbacks make sure you use [batches](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each):

```
def mark_purchased(purchased_ids)
  purchased_books = Book.unarchived.where(id: purchased_ids)
  purchased_books.find_each do |book|
    book.update(purchased: true)
  end
  purchased_books
end
```

This will be slower by an order of magnitude though as each UPDATE query has be sent to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

May I know why do you need the attr_accessor and why do you want to update the value at one go?

While fetching the unarchived data from the database you can set the value to true as a custom column named purchased using raw sql query.

```
Book.unarchived.where(id: purchased_ids).select("books.*, true as purchased")
```